# Angular directive inputs over component from another module cause an error

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive, angular-components, angular-module

There is following use case: 
-1- I have one directive (directive for dragging) in Module 1 
-2- The directive have several input (@Input()) properties coming from the component

---

The directive is working perfectly with components from Module 1.
The issue is when the directive is applied to components from Module 2.

---

**I am perfectly aware with import export mechanism regarding modules:
the component in Module 2 is declared and exported.**

---

Module 1 imports Module 2. Component is available in Module 1. It is rendered properly. When the directive is applied - everything is again fine. But since the directive posses several @Input() properties when they are applied following error occurs: (Excuse me for the small font!)

[image]

And this is the component template:

[image]

As I mentioned - the issue is when directive's properties are applied!
Would you explain what is wrong in this case - the component is exported as 
described in the docs. Module 2 is imported from Module 1 but that is still not enough.

Comment: Does it complain about binding "appDraggable" as well? Can you post your Directive code?

Comment: does module 2 import 1?

Comment: @itdoesntwork - no, the import is in reverse direction - Module 1 imports Module 2

Comment: @Freddy - here is the directive's code https://jsfiddle.net/virto/kf6azn4e/1/. I didn't applied a working example since this issue might the scenario is straightforward. And also as I mentioned above - there is no complain when the directive is applied without belonging input properties.

Comment: since the directive is in module 1 and is used in a component that exists in module 2, shouldn't 2 import 1?

Comment: Well, I suppose since Module 1 imports Module 2 and Module 2 exports by it's side component (A component), this exported component (A component) should be able to use this directive?

Comment: Sounds to me like @itdoesntwork is probably on the right track and your imports are messed up. I tested locally on a div with a made up directive attribute and a made up input attribute and Angular only complained about the input attribute. If you want the directive to be available by components within a module it is not declared in, you have to export the directive then have the second module import the first module that has the directive exported.

Comment: Or if it's a very common directive, just import the module into a root module like app.module and it'll be available to all child modules.

Comment: @Virto111 what you answer will not work.. module 1 imports module 2... module 2 does not import the directive that is in module 1 that way.. you need to redesign your modules and your imports

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly the relationship of your modules is something like this.

1. Module 1 has the directive
2. Module 2 has the component
3. Module 1 imports module 2
4. You export the component from module 2

[image]

The way to make this work would be to import module 1 into module 2.

If you want to keep things separate, one working example would be something like this.

[image]

Components exported from components module will be able to use services and directives from imported modules.

My advice for design decisions is to make everything plug-able.. Make two questions to yourself,,, How much effort will it take to copy these modules to a new project? what will be the dependencies?..

Comment: @tdoesntwork - thank you! I have to test it. But where is the logic in this behavior since angular modules serves as "boxes" and export components to be at the disposal of another components. In our project we are separating services, pipes and directives. We have also Shared module for that purpose but that directives was placed in another module. If the is true maybe the purpose is to place all directives in Shared module and from there to be imported in "consumers" modules. Anyway, for me that is strange behavior!